# Gerrit - I get a label named "Invalid-Prolog-Rules-Label-Name-"

Tags: gerrit

I get this label in my Gerrit

Invalid-Prolog-Rules-Label-Name-

[image]

Could anyone help me on why this is coming?

Comment: Did someone add `rules.pl` with invalid labels to the config branch `refs/meta/config`?

Comment: There is content in rules.pl but there are no invalid labels in the rules.pl

Comment: Got it! There was a rule which was like below
`
-overall_labels(label('', ok(user(0)))).
`
Which I was tracking since long time...

Anyway, thanks for the pointer @ElpieKay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a rule which was like below `-overall_labels(label('', ok(user(0)))).`

This was causing the problem